# Draughty PVC window

Tags: windows, pvc

Some of the PVC windows in my house lets wind and cold in, so I need to adjust them to cut off the draught. I have no experience in adjusting them, so I need to find out how I can achieve this. Any tips?

The windows look like this:

[image]

Comment: Measure the two diagonals across the window -- they should be within about 1/8" or 3-4mm of each other.  If the house has settled since being built, the window opening might have changed enough that you're no longer getting a good seal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that UPVC doors and windows can be adjusted by a technique called "toe and heeling". I have managed to fix the issue after watching the following video. I have checked and adjusted the **hinges** and the **roller cams**.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJQZXylJNRs

Answer (score 5):

If the windows are no longer sealing correctly, replacing the weather stripping is the easiest method to close drafts.

If the window is crooked (measure to make sure it's square and level) but it's otherwise working fine (opens and closes with ease, and the crookedness is not visible or bothersome) then you can apply additional weather stripping to the portions of the window that are no longer making a good seal.  If this doesn't work, or the crookedness is significant, your best option is to remove the window and re-install it level and straight.

Make sure the drafts you are experiencing are coming from the within the window frame, though.  Some drafts sneak around the outside of the frame, and you may need to place or replace insulation around the frame if the drafts are not actually coming through the window itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a [window insulator kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VSD9DG) to seal the opening for the winter.
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I need to find out how to tune the window to make it more tight at the loose spots.